# Raspberry pi 3b+, 3 green flashes, no display at all

Tags: pi-3b+, power, hdmi, boot-issues, power-light

my raspberry pi 3b+ was used to catch flightradar 24 signals. Suddenly it stopped working. On close visual inspection there were signs of water droplets close to IO pins. Now it won't boot. Red light on, green light 3 flashes and repeat, with no display from hdmi or otherwise. Orig SD card boots in a different pi.

Comment: You need to replace the files `fixup*.dat` & `start*.elf` in `/boot` or `/boot/firmware` with the latest from a bookworm card. Don't replace `kernel*.img` or `*.dtb`. That will get your old software booting on your newer RPi.

Comment: @Dougie - how do you figure that if the SD card boots in a different Pi? Seems the issue is a hardware (water damage?) issue with the 3B+

Comment: please add a clear, answerable question to your post